# Vuex working wrong

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, vuex

my vuex looks like:

```
state: {
  loadedUsers: [
    { id: 10, classId: 1, name: 'X' },
    { id: 11, classId: 1, name: 'Y' },
    { id: 13, classId: 2, name: 'Z' }
  ]
}
getters: {
  loadedUsers (state) {
    return (classId) => {
      return state.loadedUsers.find((user) => {
        return user.classId === classId
      })
    }
  }
}
```

and my computed:

```
computed: {
  users () {
    return this.$store.getters.loadedUsers(1)
  }
}
```

its just returns { id: 10, classId: 1, name: 'X' }

also when I use like

```
this.$store.getters.loadedUsers(this.$route.params.classid)
```

the classid reaching but returns empty

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns the value of the **first** element that matches. You should be using [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead. Also, you can unwrap your function/method call by one layer:

```
getters: {
  loadedUsers (state) {
    return classId => state.loadedUsers.filter((user) => {
      return user.classId === classId
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: but still returns empty because of parameter classId -- return user.classId === 1 --  thats working but above is returns empty

Comment: @mak Then you need to check if `this.$route.params.classid` is actually returning a classID. And if it does, are you parsing it to an integer (i.e. a Number), since you are doing strict comparison using `===`.